# How to fix Event View Error : It has taken too long to refresh the W3SVC counters, the stale counters are being used instead

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2008, iis-express, event-viewer

It has taken too long to refresh the W3SVC counters, the stale counters are being used instead. I don't know how to solve. We are runs some servers at this computer and this error was thrown for the lasty few days. I searched in Internet, they said, This usually happens under 100% CPU load. You can safely ignore this message as your system works as expected (response time and etc.). I'm not go with answer because we have a load balancer. If one server loads over then the second server balances the load... So need to find another way to solve this... Thanks in advance... Here I attached some details about that error log on Event Viewer.

It has taken too long to refresh the W3SVC counters, the stale counters are being used instead.

Log Name - Application

Source - IIS W3SVC-PerfCounters

Event ID - 2001

Level - Error

User- N/A

OpCode - Info

Task Category - None

Keywords - Classic

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly because of 100% CPU usage, it's actually because W3SVC is too busy handling requests for performance counters, it could be related to CPU or memory constraints. This prevents performance counter work from taking up W3SVC's time when it is busy. When things calm down, everything is automatically resolved for you.

According to [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735059(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The event log message is informational regarding performance counter
> status. The issue will be corrected by the system; you do not have to
> take any action.